# Bundle install fails, Gem install succeeds

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler, github-pages

When trying to `bundle install` on a Gemfile that contained only the GitHub Pages gem and nothing else, on Ubuntu 18.04, I got error messages telling me to try installing eventmachine using `gem install`.  That always succeeds, but `bundle install` still fails.  How can I get bundler to see that the gem is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this after many hours of struggle, by noticing that on the GitHub Pages repo there's a note that says

> Important: Make sure you have Bundler > v1.14 by running gem update bundler in your terminal before following the next steps.

I have no idea *why* this mattered but I removed my ruby packages from Ubuntu and reinstalled them, then installed bundler with rubygems, which gave me a newer version:

`sudo apt-get remove ruby
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev
sudo gem install bundler
bundler --version`

If anyone knows *why* I needed that version of bundler, or how I should have diagnosed this faster, I'd be interested to hear it.  I'm not new to programming but I'm new to Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding it might be the gem you are trying to install requires a specific feature provided by bundler. If you check the change log of bundler there is some changes related to install github based gems on how to correctly read the user git settings. So I think that might be where the problem is from.